# get feature id on click

Tags: openlayers-2, php

In my database table there are four fields(lat,lon,sensid,value).i am displaying a vector layer(point feature) by retrieving the lat, lon values from database.
Now i want to display the value, whenever i click on the feature based on id.
So how to get the feature id(database sensid) on click.I am getting lat lon values on click, but i need to get sensid.

my code is

```
var  str_array =["8541652,3397019,TATM1", "8786758,3536158,TATM2"]
 str_array = jsstr.split(';');
         var a,b,c;
    for (i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) { 
   var text = str_array[i] ;
    var  str_coord = text.split(',');
     a = parseFloat(str_coord[0]);
     b = parseFloat(str_coord[1]);
  c = parseFloat(str_coord[2]);
var feature=new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(a,b));

           vectorLayer.addFeatures(feature);
     mapPanel.map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
var selectCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectorLayer);


    function createPopup(feature) {

        popup1 = new GeoExt.Popup({
            title: 'My Popup',
            location: feature,
            width:200,
            html: '<div class="markerContent">'+feature.geometry.x +','+feature.geometry.y+'</div>',
            maximizable: true,
            collapsible: true,
            anchorPosition: "auto"
        });
       // unselect feature when the popup
       // is closed
        popup1.on({
            close: function() {
                if(OpenLayers.Util.indexOf(vectorLayer.selectedFeatures,
                                           this.feature) > -1) {
                    selectCtrl.unselect(this.feature);
                }
            }
        });
        popup1.show();
    }

   //create popup on "featureselected"


    mapPanel.map.addControl(selectCtrl);
   selectCtrl.activate();
}
vectorLayer.events.on({
        featureselected: function(e) {

            createPopup(e.feature);

        }
    });
```

Comment: you are getting 'feature.geometry', call 'feature.sensid' instead

Answer (score 1):

To get the attribute data of specific feature in case you are getting the 4 fields from DB to a layer in your project, then use **attributes** object as below:

```
function createPopup(feature) {
       var sensid = feature.attributes.sensid;
       // and add it in the html of your popup
       popup1 = new GeoExt.Popup({
        title: 'My Popup',
        location: feature,
        width:200,
        html: '<div class="markerContent">'+sensid+'</div>',
        maximizable: true,
        collapsible: true,
        anchorPosition: "auto"
    });
}
```